# TypeLoadException when injecting Context in Worker

Tags: c#, service-worker, ef-core-3.1

I currently have a Razor page application (Core 3.1) connected to a SQL Database with a Context using IdentityDbContext.  When trying to use this same context in my Worker Service, I continue to get this error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Create' in type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,
> Version=3.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
> does not have an implementation.'

Here is my Context

```
public class WarzoneTrackerContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public WarzoneTrackerContext(DbContextOptions<WarzoneTrackerContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            //if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            //{
            //    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("data source=SQLCLDevComm;initial catalog=ComQueMDS;integrated security=True;");
            //}
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasData(Seed.Players());

            foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }

            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PlayerLifetimeStats> PlayerLifetimeStats { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PlayerMatchStats> PlayerMatchStats { get; set; }

    }  // End of Class
```

Here is my Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
               .Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {

                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

                    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WarzoneTrackerContext>();

                    services.AddTransient<IMatchManager, MatchManager>();
                    services.AddTransient<IPlayerManager, PlayerManager>();
                    services.AddTransient<IRapidManager, RapidManager>();
                    //services.AddTransient<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
                    //services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WarzoneTrackerContext>();

                    //services.AddScoped<WarzoneTrackerContext>(s => new WarzoneTrackerContext(optionsBuilder.Options));

                    //services.AddScoped<WarzoneTrackerContext>(services => new WarzoneTrackerContext(optionsBuilder.Options));

                    services.AddHostedService<WarzoneWorker>();

                    services.AddDbContext<WarzoneTrackerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WarzoneConnection")));
                }).UseWindowsService();
    }
```

And here is my worker

```
public class WarzoneWorker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider services;
        private readonly ILogger<WarzoneWorker> _logger;

        public WarzoneWorker(IServiceProvider _services, ILogger<WarzoneWorker> logger)
        {
            services = _services;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
            await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<WarzoneTrackerContext>();

                    var matchManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMatchManager>();
                    var playerManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPlayerManager>();
                    var rapidManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRapidManager>();

                    _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                    await Task.Delay(300000, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
        }
    }
```

Hopefully someone can help walk me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to `Package Manager Console` and run the `dotnet restore` command.

Check the versions of the EF packages you are using. Check your package versions in `.csproj`. If you are using `preview` versions, upgrade all packages to the latest stable version.